# How can I migrate a ubuntu virtual machine which is hosted on windows Vbox to dual boot ubuntu and windows

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, windows-8

okay, so if the title of this question does not clarify my question, here is the explanation

I have a laptop with windows 8.1 and I'm running ubuntu as a virtual machine on it using VirtualBox, and I have another laptop with fresh windows 8.1 installed on it.
I need help to export that ubuntu virtual machine from one laptop and install it as a physical machine on the second laptop with dual boot with windows 8.1.

I've no idea how to do this but I know this is possible. I've read several V2P tutorials but none of them is clear or not fulfilling my requirements.

Please advice what I can do to achieve this. Any step by step instructions will be helpful.

I need to do this urgently.

Thank you.

Comment: No time for a step by step guide but the easiest approach is using some cloning software to copy the partition from the VM to the real disk.

Comment: Thanks for your input. any suggestion for the cloning software?